# HostHeader is not recognized

Tags: c#, iis-7, webserver, localhost, hostheaders

I have a web service with its host header e.g. "https: //Servicemonitor/service1.asmx". And we are referring this service in the web site configuration file.But the website was not able to connect to the webservice.

But when I mention the webservice IP address("https: //160.17.25.120/service1.asmx") in the websites configuration it works and it was able to communicate with the service.

Any idea how to fix this ? The website has binding of 443 and also the webservice has 443 binding.Both have windows and anonymous authentication enabled.both run with same app pool account emea/authtest.

Comment: Does your web-service respond *generally* on that address? i.e. if you type `https: //Servicemonitor/service1.asmx` into a web-browser (inside your network, obviously; on the actual machine affected would be even better) : does it respond with the correct info page?

Comment: https: //Servicemonitor/service1.asmx doesn't open on the server , but it opens successfully on my local machine.

Comment: So... What *do* you get on the server? A yellow screen of death? Basically, until you fix that: nothing is going to work. This sounds mainly like an IIS configuration issue.